# Populate second dropdown based on value of first dropdown from List<Map<String, Object>>

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I am creating this part of the app in Flutter. The user will have to select the car brand then the second dropdown will be filled with specific models for that car brand. The problem I am having is because the data is being sourced from a static json data:

```
static List<Map<String, Object>> cars = [
{
  "brand": "Alfa Romeo",
  "models": [
    "145",
    "146",
    "147",
    "155",
    "156",
    "156 Sportwagon",
    "159",
    "159 Sportwagon",
    "164",
    "166",
    "4C",
    "Brera",
    "GTV",
    "MiTo",
    "Crosswagon",
    "Spider",
    "GT",
    "Giulietta",
    "Giulia"
  ]
},
{
  "brand": "Audi",
  "models": [
    "100",
    "100 Avant",
    "80",
    "80 Avant",
    "80 Cabrio",
    "90",
    "A1",
    "A2",
    "A3",
    "A3 Cabriolet",
    "A3 Limuzina",
    "A3 Sportback",
    "A4",
    "A4 Allroad",
    "A4 Avant",
    "A4 Cabriolet",
    "A5",
    "A5 Cabriolet",
    "A5 Sportback",
    "A6",
    "A6 Allroad",
    "A6 Avant",
    "A7",
    "A8",
    "A8 Long",
    "Q3",
    "Q5",
    "Q7",
    "R8",
    "RS4 Cabriolet",
    "RS4/RS4 Avant",
    "RS5",
    "RS6 Avant",
    "RS7",
    "S3/S3 Sportback",
    "S4 Cabriolet",
    "S4/S4 Avant",
    "S5/S5 Cabriolet",
    "S6/RS6",
    "S7",
    "S8",
    "SQ5",
    "TT Coupé",
    "TT Roadster",
    "TTS"
  ]
}];
```

If the user selects "Alfa Romeo", the items/values in the key "models" should be displayed in the second dropdown.

I was able to make the first dropdown working but I am confused on how to do the 2nd dropdown:

```
Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, top: 24, bottom: 10),
                      child: Text(
                        "Select your car brand:",
                        style: Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .subtitle1!
                            .copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).hintColor),
                      ),
                    ),

                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
                      child: DropdownButton<String>(
                        isDense: true,
                        hint: new Text("Select"),
                        value: _mySelection,
                        onChanged: (newValue) {

                          setState(() {
                            _mySelection = newValue!;
                          });

                          print (_mySelection);
                        },
                        items: MapUtils.cars.map((Map map) {
                          return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: map["brand"].toString(),
                            child: new Text(
                              map["brand"],
                            ),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, top: 24, bottom: 10),
                      child: Text(
                        "Select your car model:",
                        style: Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .subtitle1!
                            .copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).hintColor),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
                      child: DropdownButton<String>(
                        isDense: true,
                        hint: new Text("Select"),
                        value: MapUtils.cars.,
                        onChanged: (newValue) {

                          setState(() {
                            _mySelection = newValue!;
                          });

                          print (_mySelection);
                        },
                        items: MapUtils.cars.map((Map map) {
                          print(map["brand"]);
                          return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: map["brand"].toString(),
                            child: new Text(
                              map["brand"],
                            ),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to have a variable for the currently selected car's models. `List<String> selectedCarModels = []` which will be updated on your `onChanged` of the dropdown.

```dart
onChanged: (newValue) {
 setState(() {
  _mySelection = newValue!;
  selectedCarModels = cars.where((c)=>c['brand']==newValue).first['models'] as List<String>;
 print (_mySelection);
},
```

The `onchanged` could be easier if the `newValue` was of `Map<String,Object>` so you could change the `selectedCarModels=newValue['models']` this way.

Comment: I have an error on the 4th line: The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.

Comment: I have editted the answer, I had `()` at `first` now it's removed. It should work fine.

Comment: Next error is: A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<String>'.

Comment: Thank you, you are the best!

Answer (score 0):

> disable the dropdown for model selection until the brand is selected
> and as soon as brand is selected take the index and pass it to the dropdown
> items property

```
items: MapUtils.cars[index].map((Map map) {
                      return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: map["models"].toString(),
                        child: new Text(
                          map["models"],
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList()
```